# Submit button is not clicking even though python script is executed-Python Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my testing, one of the page is having "Submit" button and when i try to click  on submit button is not working (not clicking) even though script is executed.

Below is the HTML code  for the submit button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_button" value="1" type="submit">
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
Submit
```

I have written the scripts as like below to find submit button element.

```
time.sleep(6)
sub = web.find_element_by_name("submit_button")
sub.click()
```

I have tried to find element using "Xpath" (Absolute XPath and Relative XPath) as well and observed that did not work. one more thing is that,the accessible page is in "iframe"
and i have access that as like below

```
web.switch_to.frame("page-content")
```

To confirm that whether the scripts is running or not i have modified above code as like below.

```
time.sleep(6)
print ("hello")
sub = web.find_element_by_name("submit_button")
print ("hello1")
sub.click()
print ("hello2")
```

From above code i got know that scripts were executing successfully
Please guide me what is the issue?
Answers are much appreciable!

Comment: So you are neither getting exception nor submit button is clicked? Could you confirm whether your code is able to do any action on other elements present in that particular frame in which submit button is there? Also make sure that your locator uniquely locate submit button, if multiple submit button are found by your locator either by xpath or name then you will experience such scenario

Comment: As workaround you can try call `submit()` with any element within `form` instead of clicking Submit button

Comment: Can you consider updating your exact code block and relevant code block near around the iFrame & the button? Thanks

Comment: Without the actual url it's hard to help you. Your code in itself seems ok. Could you provide the url?

Comment: @Andersson, thanks for the suggestion used .submit() function, now able to click.